# Android SQLite - How to select all sub class entries from super class table?

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have a data set of Notes, with Note as super class of TextNote and PhotoNote.

I've put this into 3 tables:

**Note:**

```
id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
type       TEXT
created    INTEGER
modified   INTEGER
t_id       INTEGER FOREIGN KEY -> TextNote 
p_id       INTEGER FOREIGN KEY -> PhotoNote
```

**TextNote:**

```
id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
text       TEXT
```

**PhotoNote:**

```
id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
image           BLOB
description     TEXT
```

**Problem:**
I want to show all Notes in MainActivity as timeline, so I need one `SELECT ... ORDER BY modified DESC` query which returns a table with every Note as its sub class.

I don't want to set up a query for each table, because sorting each result array by last modified date would be too messy for java, as much as I know.

**My attempt** was to use sub queries like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
       (SELECT 
          note.id AS t_id, 
          type, 
          created, 
          modified, 
          text, 
          note.t_id AS ref_id 
             FROM TABLE_TEXT_NOTE 
             INNER JOIN TABLE_NOTE 
             ON TABLE_NOTE.t_id = TABLE_TEXT_NOTE.id),
       (SELECT 
           note.id AS p_id, 
           type, 
           created, 
           modified, 
           image, 
           description, 
           note.p_id AS ref_id
               FROM TABLE_PHOTO_NOTE 
               INNER JOIN TABLE_NOTE
               ON TABLE_NOTE.p_id = TABLE_PHOTO_NOTE.id) 
ORDER BY modified DESC
```

But this didn't work out. I also tried `INNER JOIN` without the sub queries, which seems not to be the right approach too.

**Question:**
Maybe I should consider reorganizing my tables?
What is the right approach to get every Note in one select statement ordered by `modified`?

Comment: Do you need to use a relational database?  This would be much easier with a document-oriented NoSQL database.

Comment: I thought about this too. Because i just started developing in Java and come from NodeJS with MongoDB. 
But this is a Group-Project for my studies and I don't want to confuse my colleagues with some new stuff...

Answer (score 1):

You can pretend to have a single notes table with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW SubNoteData AS
SELECT id, text, NULL AS image, 'T' AS type
FROM TextNote
UNION ALL
SELECT id, description, image, 'P' AS type
FROM PhotoNote;
```

(This requires avoiding duplicate IDs. But you should use the same ID for the same note anyway.)

Having two ID columns in `Note` is cumbersome; joining would be easier with a single `note_id` column, and maybe a type column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have read about the `UNION` clause before posting this question and I wonder, because the SQLite reference says the number of columns in each `SELECT` statement have to be equal.
[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm)
Still I will give it a try later, because I am working on a workaround right now.

Comment: This query *does* have equal numbers of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You may store all the data for Note, TextNote, and PhotoNote objects in one table with columns for **id, type, created, modified, text, image, description,** and **discriminator** ; the **discriminator** column identifying the type of the row object (Note, TextNote, or PhotoNote). Of course, the columns **text, image,** and **description** should be nullable.

If you want to query for only the Note objects; you can use a SELECT statement with only the relevant columns for Note and a WHERE clause like **discriminator = 'Note'**. You may also query for all kinds of Note objects (selecting all the columns) and then interpret each row as per the value of the **discriminator** column.